# Setting an S4 slot to function and representing a neural network layer

Tags: r, list, closures, r-s4

I am attempting to write some classes in R.  Here is the start of a neural network layer class.  It is generating warnings and errors that I don't know how to correct.

```
# Slot definitions
setClass(
 Class="neuralNetworkLayer",
 representation=representation(
   input = "vector",
   linearOutput = "vector",
   squashedOutput = "vector",
   hasBias = "logical",
   bias = "vector",
   weights = "vector",
   gains = "matrix",
   squashFcn = "closure",
   squashFcnDerivative = "closure"
 )
)

# Constructors
NeuralNetworkLayer <- function(nInput,nOutput,hasBias=TRUE,squashFcn,squashFcnDerivative) {
  nc = list(
    input = c(rep(NA,nInput)),
    linearOutput = c(rep(NA,nOutput)),
    squashedOutput = c(rep(NA,nOutput)),
    hasBias = hasBias,
    bias = c(rep(NA,nOutput)),
    weights = c(rep(NA,nOutput)),
    gain = matrix(data=weights, nrow = nInput, ncol = nOutput),
    squashFcn = squashFcn,   # source of warning / error
    squashFcnDerivative = squashFcnDerivative,

    get = function(x) nc[[x]],
    set = function(x, value) nc[[x]] <<- value,
    props = list()
  )
  #Add a few more functions
  nc$addProp = function(name, value) {
    p <- nc$props
    p[[name]] <- value
    assign('props', p, envir=nc)
  }
  nc <- list2env(nc)
  class(nc) <- "NeuralNetwork"
  return(nc)
}

  tanhDerivative <- function(x) {
    d = 1 - tan(x)^2  
    return(d)
  }

  test <- NeuralNetworkLayer(nInput=4,nOutput=5,hasBias=TRUE,
                             squashFcn=tanh,squashFcnDerivative=tanhDerivative)
```

The messages generated are

```
Warning message:
undefined slot classes in definition of "neuralNetworkLayer": squashFcn(class "closure"),
squashFcnDerivative(class "closure")

Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'
```

Both messages indicate that the base class closure can not be used for a slot.  How to pass a function?

Taking the advice from the two answers, the following code can be generated.  This addresses the original question of passing a function to a slot, and then using that function.  For completeness, the revised neural network layer class is present.

```
setClass(
  Class="neuralNetworkLayer",
  representation=representation(
    nInput = "numeric",
    nOutput = "numeric",
    squashFcn = "function",
    derivSquashFcn = "function",
    gains = "matrix",
    hasBias = "logical",
    bias = "matrix",
    linOutput = "matrix",
    squashOutput = "matrix"
  )
)
getClass("neuralNetworkLayer")
getSlots("neuralNetworkLayer")

sf <- function(x){
  f = tanh(x)
  return(f)
}
dsf <- function(x) {
  d = 1 - tan(x)^2  
  return(d)
}

# Create an object of class 
hh = new("neuralNetworkLayer",squashFcn=sf,nInput=5,nOutput=5,hasBias=TRUE,
                        derivSquashFcn = dsf) 

hh@squashFcn(3)
hh@derivSquashFcn(3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error/warning :

```
 undefined slot classes in definition of "neuralNetworkLayer": squashFcn(class "closure")
```

means that slot is not defined beacuse the type "closure" is not defined.

You try To define a slot(attribute) as a generic function one idea is to use `ANY` ( the default for slot I think) type:

```
neuralNetworkLayer <- 
setClass(
  Class="neuralNetworkLayer",
  representation=representation(
    squashFcn = "ANY"
  )
)
```

Then ,for example you instantiate your class like this :

```
# Constructors
hh = neuralNetworkLayer(squashFcn=function(x)print(x)) ## dummy function here 
hh@squashFcn(10)
[1] 10
```

That's said , I think you should consider to define your functions slots as a real method(see **setMethod**) . Methods are to have typed (safer) objects Otheriwse there is no good reason the reason to use S4 system and easier to use S3 method.

Comment: I updated the class, but now the evaluation of the matrix multiplication doesn't work.  If you have a minute, could you review the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you are defining a `neuralNetworkLayer` S4 class while your constructor doesn't make any use of it. You just are creating a normal R list (no slots in the returning object of `NeuralNetworkLayer`). In your constructor you should call `new` somewhere.

Anyhow, your error doesn't have nothing to do with `closure` as you might think. You just didn't define the `weights` object that it happens to be also an R function. When you say:

```
    weights = c(rep(NA,nOutput)),
    gains = matrix(data=weights, nrow = nInput, ncol = nOutput),
```

you are creating an element of a list named `weights`, but you are not creating an object named `weights`. When you define the `gains` element, R just finds for `weights` its R function and tries to coerce it to put it into a matrix, giving the error. You can just define `weights` in your first line of `NeuralNetworkLayer`:

```
    weights = c(rep(NA,nOutput))
```

and then, when you define `nc`, replace the first line I wrote above with:

```
    weights = weights,
```

and your function won't give any error.

For the warning part of the definition of the S4 class, just use `function` instead of `closure`. However, as you have defined your constructor, you may well not define it at all.

Comment: I used this information to correctly represent the class and data.

Comment: I updated the class, but now the evaluation of the matrix multiplication doesn't work.  If you have a minute, could you review the updated code.

Comment: You should create another question. Anyway, it seems that you are using R like Java or C++. When you call `setWeights` you are not modifying your object. Objects in R are passed by copying them in the body of a function. Just check your `hh` before and after the call of the method. You may need to read `?setReferenceClass`. Another issue is that you are not properly defining the `signature` of `evaluate`: it has two args, while you defined it with just one.

Comment: typo: `setRefClass` instead of `setReferenceClass`.

Comment: The setRefClass recommendation guided implementation of the neural network layer class.